# Invoking rules from case builder solution using java API

Tags: java, web-services, filenet, ibm-case-manager

We are trying to integrate **IBM case manager rules** (Newly added feature in `IBM case manager 5.2`) with Java API. But we couldn't able to find any Java API to fetch the rules integrated with case manager.

We're already integrated rules and tested that using process designer. But we are looking for how to get/fetch these rules from Java API.

It will be really helpful, if someone guide us by giving any useful links/ code samples/ documents. Any help is really appreciated..

[image]

> *Update :*

My application should follow few rules like,

1. Question1 ---> Yes ------> Question3
2. Question1 ---> No ------> Question2

The `Question1` and `yes/no` response will come from java API, based on the answer rule engine returns the next question

Comment: Are you sure that ICM is the right SW for this task? It looks like questionaries ... may be it will be better to use appropriate platform? Something like e-Learning systems?

Comment: But if you really want to do this on ICM you can create questionaries as set of user-tasks with responses and route to the next question related with the answers? (User task in CM have property for Answers and Route can be related with Answer). 
You can try to create custom BPM operation to execute your rules, you can create ICN plugin for editing your rules and store it into Content Engine.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to execute rules via Case Manager API.

Rules engine in Case Manager it is the iLog rules, so you can try to execute it via iLog API, but I am not sure that it will be work, and I am sure that it will be not supported but IBM :))

Can you explain why do you need to execute rule via API?